# WebStorm/IntelliJ autosuggest doesn't recognize named imports

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

I tried installing extra TypeScript libraries as suggested by others. My project JavaScript Language is set to ReactJSX. However when using the auto import, it only imports modules as if default imports. It recognizes the correct package, just doesn't do a named import.

[image]

[image]

The second image will fail as it should be a named import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-47925 that is planned to be fixed in 2020.3.

BTW, according to the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction), the preferred way to import `react-bootstrap` components is using the default imports like `import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';`